# SegNet for CT images pretrained weights

Tags: tensorflow, keras, image-segmentation, conv-neural-network, vgg-net

I'm  trying to train a SegNet for segmentation task on ct images (with Keras TF).
I'm using VGG16 pretrained weights but I had a problem with the first convolutional layer because I'm using grayscale images but VGG was trained on rgb ones.
I solved that using second method of [this](https://github.com/RohitSaha/VGG_Imagenet_Weights_GrayScale_Images) (can't use first method because requires too much memory).
However it didn't help me, values are really bad (trained for 100 epochs).

Should I train the first convolutional layer from scratch?

Answer (score 1):

You can try to add a Conv2D before the vgg. Something like :

```
> Your Input(shape=(height,width,1))

Conv2D(filters=3,kernel_size=1, padding='same',activation='relu')

> The VGG pretrained network (input = (height,width,3))
```

is interesting in your case because 1x1 convolution is usually employed to change the depth of your object.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I'll give it a try!